# How to imply $T^*=-T \Rightarrow T^2+I=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question:

$$
T:V \to V
$$
Linear transformation in inner product space.

Given:

$$
T^* = -T
$$

Prove that $\forall a \in R \to I-aT$ Invertible.

---

I saw that i had a mistake, please close the question or delete it. Sorry and thanks for the help in seeing my error.

Comment: This is certainly not always true, for instance $T=0$ satisfies the former condition but not the latter.

Answer (score 1):

$(I-aT)(I+aT)=I-a^2T=(1+a^2)I$. This implies that the inverse of $I-aT$ is ${1\over{1+a^2}}(I+aT)$.

Comment: Thanks, understood, but i asked about the $T^2-I=0$, how did they get to this?

Comment: I'm not sure how can they get. That equality seems wrong without further assumption on $T$.

Comment: Another question is on Tsemo’s answer, how did the first equation worked, how did he get to $I-a^2T$ And not $I-a^2T^2$? And from that how did you get to $(1+a^2)I$?